# Which method for accessing a 2D array in C is most effective? (Using Pointers)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

If you have a function that takes the pointer of an array, would there be any use in using pointers to each element in the array, or is it redundant? For example:

```
int sum(int(*arr)[3]) {
    int i,j, sum = 0;
    for (i =0; i < ROW ; i ++) {
        for (j =0; j < COL ; j ++) {
            sum = sum + *(*( arr +i )+j);
        }
    }
}
```

Would using arr[i][j] be the same in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr[i]` is required by the standard to be equivalent to `*(arr + i)` so no, there is no point in not using `arr[i]` which is more readable.

Speeding up 2d array access is a complex topic. There are some techniques for performance improvement, but those take hardware architecture (e.g. cache) into account are are related to access patterns rather than access syntax.

Comment: Correct, but would using *(arr+i) take up fewer resources? Or is the answer much more complicated as you noted?

Comment: @Ailany what resources? The answer is simple regarding the array index operator vs pointer dereference: it's 100% equivalent. It generates identical asm code as you can see here: https://godbolt.org/z/dYWz3bcof